# How to res convert to Like res2

Tags: javascript, json

```
 res = [{name:"sonu",roll:34,file:"asj.jpg", img_id:'1'},{name:"sonu",roll:34,file:"asj1.jpg", img_id:'2'},     {name:"sonu",roll:34,file:"asj2.jpg", img_id:'3'},{name:"dip",roll:67,file:"fgd3.jpg", img_id:'4'},     {name:"dip",roll:67,file:"fgd4.jpg", img_id:'5'},{name:"dip",roll:67,file:"fgd5.jpg", img_id:'6'}]
```

res convert to like res2

```
res2 = [{name:"sonu",roll:34, image: [{file:"asj.jpg",img_id:'1'},{file:"asj1.jpg", img_id:'2'},{file:"asj2.jpg", img_id:'3'}]},
{name:"dip",roll:67, image: [{file:"fgd3.jpg", img_id:'4'},{file:"fgd4.jpg", img_id:'5'},{file:"fgd5.jpg", img_id:'6'}]}]
```

Comment: You'll need to use some array methods, map is a good one - although, I think [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) would be better now that I've looked at it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask show what you tried and where you encounter problems while trying

Comment: are all sonu 34, and all dip 67?

Comment: yes all sonu 34 and all dip 67.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var groupBy = function (xs, key) {
  return xs.reduce(function (rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
  }, {});
};

var res0= groupBy(res, 'name');

var res2 = [];
Object.keys(res0).forEach((item) => {
  
  var newObj = { name: item, roll: res0[item][0].roll, image: [] };

  res0[item].forEach((obj) => {
    newObj.image.push({ file: obj.file, img_id: obj.img_id });
  });

  res2.push(newObj);
});
```